# access parent for each loop in nested loop in php

Tags: php, loops

I have an array that I use a loop to run throught, the code below:

```
foreach($arry as $parentkey => $parentvalue){
  $secondloop = explode(",",$parentvalue);
  foreach($secondloop as $childvalue){
    echo $parentkey.' '.$childvalue ;
  }
}
```

When I run it, it does not display the parentkey. Does php not support that kind of loop?
How do I make it display the parent key? What would be the best way to walk throught the loop to get the desired result?

original array

```
     Array ( [1] => 2,3,10,11,27,28,35,36,165,37,38,40,41,42,43,44,46,49,50,61,62,65,66,75,67,71,69,72,73,74,76,96,90,91,97,107,118,147,119,122,139,142,148,149,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,181 [2] => 39,102,94,98,92,121 [3] => 45,77,117,103,109,99 [4] => 47,78,146,105,113,115,104 [5] => 48,79,106,114,120,110 [6] => 68,93,116,111,112 [7] => 140,150 [8] => 141,151 [9] => 143,144,166,153 [10] => 145,154,159 [11] => 157,155 [12] => 158,156 [13] => 160 [14] => 161 [15] => 162 [16] => 163 [17] => 164 )
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it, how does your original array look like?

Comment: i want to see the key of the parent array beside the exploded value

Comment: And what result do you get now?

Comment: explode is a string function, in your code the value is not a string, is that just a cut&copy mistake?

Comment: The nested loop is fine. The problem must be in your original array. Also change the echo to something like `echo $parentkey.' '.$childvalue.'<br/>';` to make it easier to interpret the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information given, your code works, see the following cleaned up example.

```
<?php

$arry = array(
    1 => '2,3,10,11,27,28,35,36,165,37,38,40,41,42,43,44,46,49,50,61,62,65,66,75,67,71,69,72,73,74,76,96,90,91,97,107,118,147,119,122,139,142,148,149,168,169,170,171,17$
    2 => '39,102,94,98,92,121',
    3 => '45,77,117,103,109,99',
    4 => '47,78,146,105,113,115,104',
    5 => '48,79,106,114,120,110',
    6 => '68,93,116,111,112',
    7 => '140,150',
    8 => '141,151',
    9 => '143,144,166,153',
    10 => '145,154,159',
    11 => '157,155',
    12 => '158,156',
    13 => '160',
    14 => '161',
    15 => '162',
    16 => '163',
    17 => '164'
);

foreach($arry as $parentkey => $parentvalue){
        $secondloop = explode(",",$parentvalue);
        foreach($secondloop as $childvalue){
                echo 'Parent key: ' . $parentkey . ', child value: ' . $childvalue . PHP_EOL;
        }
}
```

Comment: @VictorKilo, no, the dump of the output clearly shows my kind of array structure. If the $parentvalue would not be a string, you would have way more index keys in the print_r dump.

Comment: Good call ;) It's late.  I should sleep instead of trying to think.